# Logic for items binding in RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I would like to add some logic to item when binding in ViewHolder for RecyclerView.
My Adapter looks like this:

```
class MyAdapter(): ListAdapter<Item, MyAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(DiffCallback()){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder{
        val binding = MyItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder(private val binding: MyItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        
        fun bind(item: Item){
            binding.apply {
                tvStar.text = ""
                tvValueA.text = item.ValueA
                tvValueB.text = item.ValueB                

            }
        }
```

I need to change tvStar.text depends on values in item.ValueA and item.ValueB. Something like this:

```
binding.apply {
                if (item.ValueA == 0.toFloat()){
                    tvStar.text = ""
                }else if (item.ValueA != item.ValueB){
                    tvStar.text = "-"
                } else if (item.ValueA == item.ValueB){
                    tvStar.text = "*"
                }
}
```

If ValueA (type of Float) is equal zero, text should be empty, if both values are different and ValueA is not zero then text should be "-" and when both values are the same, the text should be "*".
I tried this solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work, what is the error or unexpected result?

Comment: Try adding Log.d, or breakpoints in code

Comment: @mightyWOZ thanks both of you, I wrote wrong name of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
class MyAdapter(): ListAdapter<Item, MyAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    ...
    inner class ItemViewHolder(private val binding: MyItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(item: Item){
            binding.apply {
                tvStar.text = when {
                    item.ValueA == 0f -> ""
                    item.ValueA == item.ValueB -> "*"
                    else -> "-"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And make sure the item at that position has the correct value of `ValueA` and `ValueB`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code like this. It looks like I have some mistakes in names of values.

```
binding.apply {
                tvStar.text =  if (item.ValueA == 0.toFloat()){
                    ""
                }else (if (item.ValueA != item.ValueB){
                                "-"
                            } else if (item.ValueA == item.ValueB){
                                "*"
                            } else{
                                ""
                            })}
```